# Nginx log rotation

Tags: linux, nginx, logrotate, log-rotation

Can this be explained :

```
[ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

(the content of /etc/logrotate.d/nginx) ?

Why is this not as

```
[ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] && kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

because should we not be sending the signal only if nginx.pid file exists ? if pid won't exist, then nginx is not running and we cannot send a signal to the master process ?

Answer (score 1):

Both statements perform the same function but have different exit codes.

```
[ ! condition ] || action
[ condition ] && action
```

Both statements perform *action* only if *condition* is true. The only alternative is to **not** perform the *action* when the *condition* is false.

If *condition* is true the exit code of the entire statement is the exit code of the *action*.

It is when the *condition* if false that the exit code of the two statements differ, because it is the exit code of the `[ ... ]` element.